# how to properly use images files (gif) on java applets?

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I am writing a game using Java (eclipse) and I managed to get the basics down completely.  I used .gif files for the game sprites and loaded them with

```
Image java.applet.Applet.getImage(URL url, String name)
```

and under eclipse my code runs perfectly, but when I either add the applet onto a runnable JFrame, or embed it onto a website, it explodes with errors, most notably

```
access denied("java.io.filepermission read")
```

after getting very frustrated and searching for hours on every forum and tutorial I could find, I came across something called the sandboxing error, which I have read means that applets cannot access images on the filesystem the class is on.

if that is the error I am getting, and applets can't access files or images(which seems silly to me, then whats the point of applets?) then How can I use images in applets if I can't load them from files? or more to the point, how do I get my perfectly error-free code to run outside of eclipse so I can "distribute" it?

Comment: When you say it works fine, do you mean it works fine on your computer and does website reside on a server other then your dev box (i.e. when you get access denied the applet is part of a site running on a different machine)?

Comment: I mean that when I run eclipse and tell it to compile and run, no errors, but when I try to run it from an embedded applet (on a locally saved html file) or adding it to a JFrame and running as an executable it doesn't run because of file permission errors.

Comment: You can always store the images on the same host as where your applet codebase is. No security exceptions that way. Otherwise, if you think about it, those images will not exist on the machines of everyone who accesses your Applet right? Even if there was no sandbox your current setup wouldn't work. Your two choices are 1) Host the images on the server where the applet codebase is, or 2) Deploy the images in the applet jar itself

Comment: There are various things you have reported that don't add up.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  The `Applet.getImage(..)` method will work for sand-boxed applets as long as the JRE recognizes that the URL is to the local server.  *"it explodes with errors,"*  Copy/paste them rather than paraphrase.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check where are the images stored on your server?  What user is the owner of those images, and is that user different from the user that the web server runs under?  If so I would change the permissions on the images and the directory where the images reside so that they include read access to the user that your web server runs under.

A similar question was asked on Stackvoerflow:
[how to provide access permission for applet to write on file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660646/how-to-provide-access-permission-for-applet-to-write-on-file-system)

As was mentioned by the other poster it looks like you have to make sure your applet is signed:http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html

Comment: I stored the images in the same directory as the classes, 
example:
URL url = getDocumentBase();
...
Image img = getImage(url, "whatever.gif");


I tried running it from a local html file in the same directory off my HD, no go. tried acessing it with my from a second computer, no go.

Answer (score 0):

By default, applets cannot access the local file system. The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#images) tells you how to use images in an applet correctly.